# how to open *.dbf spreadsheet file in C#

Tags: c#, dbf

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. In a simple Windows application I just want to have one form with a datagrid and a button that open the *.dbf spreadsheet file and put all the data in the dataGrid. I'm using C#. Could you help?

Comment: isn't dbf the old Clipper DB file ?

Comment: it can be opened with MS Excel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll find the basic code for setting up an ODBC connection here: http://joskovski.blogspot.com/2010/03/reading-dbf-files-from-net.html

And then you can uses something like `dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;`